# how to skip specific columns while taking input from csv file in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am taking input from Csv file in jmeter to test my API request. I need to to skip a few column values. Is there any way to do this?

Let's say my .csv has columns:
**User, password, Location, Status, Amount**

I am interested to take **User, Password, Amount** columns as input into my api request.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore using them in your API request. E.g., if you API requires a JSON payload with only the three columns, you have mentioned above, you just need to substitute them as shows below (assuming everything is a String value except Amount in this JSON).

```
{
 "username": "${User}",
 "password": "${Password}",
 "Amount": ${Amount}
}
```

Since you are selectively substituting only the three column values, you are controlling the skip/ignore and not JMeter.